# Unhandled error in SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, soap

I have a web service which have a method called

public string GenerateReport(string sessionID, string reportID, string reportType, string userid)

i am passing params from db as soap

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <GenerateReport>
    <sessionID>372</sessionID>
    <reportID>172</reportID>
    <reportType>P</reportType>
    <userid>IBOX</userid>
    </GenerateReport>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

but i am getting the error like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
 <soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)</faultstring>
<detail />
 </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

pls help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, this seems like a problem with the endpoint URL. You're getting exception for missing action and the action is specified there.

Try making the endpoint URL look something like this:

http(s)://your_server/your_page.aspx/**actionname**

Where actionname is the name of your method - GenerateReport.

If this does not help continue searching for the problem in the way you call the service (endpoint URL, message format), not in the data. Changing data will not help you. You may also use the wsdl, generated by the web-service and browse it in SOAP UI - this will help you avoid such problems altogether.

Good luck!